# jQuery selecting name attribute with []

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way I can use a selector for a name attribute that has [] at the end? The below code won't work, is there an alternative?

```
$("[name=some_attribute[]]")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `'` to wrap the name:

```
$("[name='text[]']");
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/arBjk/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can escape with backslashes. So:

```
$("[name=some_attribute\\[\\]]")
```

Note that since I'm writing the backslash in a string literal, I have to escape it (with another backslash).

You can also use quotes around the value:

```
$("[name='some_attribute[]']")
// or
$('[name="some_attribute[]"]')
```

These are both actually CSS things rather than jQuery things: The value used in an attribute selector must be a [CSS identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) or [a string](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#strings).

Answer (score 2):

### Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/arBjk/2/)**

Guess this is what you need

```
$("*[name$='\\[\\]']")
```

OR

```
 $("[name$='\\[\\]']")
```

OR

```
$("[name$='[]']")
```

Hope this helps, Thank you

Comment: Oh didn't see this answer, removed mine ^^ He clearly sais "that has [] at the end", this is only right one at the moment. dunno why others get votes.